# JavaFX Button hover scaling

Tags: java, css, javafx

I started learning about JavaFX effects, but I can't seem to find any relevant information on button scalling on hover.

I'm guessing it could be done by either JavaFX code with the Scale transition or with CSS.
In CSS I have found a way to grow button's on mouse hover, but I don't know how to implement it to JavaFX.

Here is the grow hover effect in pure css code for html:

```
.hvr-grow {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

How could I transform that css code into fx-css code? Is css code the same as fx-css code? (meaning do i just have to put "-fx-[buttonID]"in front and thats it?)

If there is any information reguarding CSS animations and stuff like that for JavaFX css, I would like to know.

Could you please help me with this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node) has a `-fx-scale-x`, `-fx-scale-y` and an `-fx-scale-z` CSS property, which have the default value of **1**. `Node` is the superclass of `Button` therefore these properties are inherited.

To apply it to any button on hover in your application, add this css selectpr to your stylesheet:

```
.button:hover {
    -fx-scale-x: 1.1;
    -fx-scale-y: 1.1;
    -fx-scale-z: 1.1;
}
```

To see what CSS styles the different controls have you can check the linked guide and you can also check the [default stylesheet for JavaFX 8 (modena.css)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).

To learn about how to style your application with CSS, you can check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

Comment: Thank  you very very much!!

Comment: this doesn't have a transition, even though the question clearly mentions transition of 0.3sec